# How to update value when using Async Pipes in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I would like to getting the latest value. There are 2 API. one is updatePhoneNo and another one is getPhoneValue.  After I called updatePhoneNo  API, the getPhoneValue is loaded and updated the latest value. But the html page is not update. How to solve it?

TS:

```
projects$: Observable<CustDetaill>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.projects$ = this.custService.getPhoneValue(this.custno);
}



update(){
   this.custService.updatePhoneNo(this.custphoneno).subscribe(
    res => {
        this.projects$.next(this.custphoneno);
    });
}
```

HTML

```
{{(projects$ |async)?.phoneNo}}
```

Comment: I think you are missing the crucial part of your code. You should include the parts where `getPhoneValue` is loaded and something is updated. Otherwise we are only able to guess what the problem could be.

Comment: can you please provide a link to your issue in codesandbox or stackliz?

Comment: are you sure that you are really initializing `projects$` as an observable and not a subject? Usually it should not be possible to call `next` on a plain observable. Nevertheless you aren't doing anything with the response. Are you sure that `this.custphoneno` does contain the updated value?

Comment: can you add the code for this function custService.getPhoneValue ? thanks!

Comment: see that if you're using [ChangeDetectionStrategy](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy).onPush you need call to [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef).markForCheck()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should treat it as observable and use it from the typeScript like this

```
this.projects$.next(newValue);
```

> update

i saw your edit .. ok first you need to change type projects$

```
 projects$: BehaviorSubject<CustDetaill>;
```

and make it takes its value with the "next" key work
i wrote an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-newton-6bui9u?file=/src/app/app.component.ts) for you .. hope it can help

Comment: hello, i updated the code. But still not working.

Comment: I updated the answer and created and example .. please check it